# Disk /dev/sda: doesn't contain a valid partition table

Tags: partitioning, raid, testdisk

I had a Software Raid 1, and somehow it got corrupted and I cannot boot it. I am trying to fix it through rescue mode and this is what I am getting from both drives. Is there any way to fix the partition tables, or recover the files?

I tried testdisk but I have failed till now fixing it.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 240 GB (=> 223 GiB) doesn't contain a valid partition table
Disk /dev/sdb: 240 GB (=> 223 GiB) doesn't contain a valid partition table

root@rescue# lsblk
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0    0     4G  1 loop
sda     8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
sdb     8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk

root@rescue#fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZ7WD240
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZ7LM240
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


root@rescue# od /dev/sda | head -n20
0000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
0225040 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
0225100 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
0225140 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
0225200 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
0225240 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
0225300 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
0225340 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777
*
0225400 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
*
0225440 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777 177777


root@rescue# od /dev/sdb | head -n20
0000000 157126 060501 077736 077660 145433 146476 063625 011126
0000020 013502 116356 102467 070177 055416 163604 147374 034037
0000040 107232 027711 143565 172533 176164 130712 060157 125231
0000060 161246 161710 167427 101536 034313 035230 032143 152635
0000100 046547 063152 004167 143714 064060 046635 127371 041717
0000120 004277 064662 032027 025556 177314 175062 107017 047265
0000140 040162 001155 113024 171021 174430 014347 110314 115104
0000160 130207 051177 172414 170650 156411 034656 053730 177151
0000200 015255 103520 125574 151324 063441 176756 066023 156244
0000220 101711 142566 136065 103107 117535 131530 075427 077601
0000240 025012 077322 020011 171524 146444 035727 064304 052573
0000260 153516 017570 154234 140677 143632 164264 072514 037202
0000300 105175 050232 162404 174265 126050 161735 063461 030425
0000320 057333 065434 171514 124643 140101 016156 067340 106600
0000340 176537 137106 047540 175607 104721 127472 106773 127672
0000360 034763 025443 101615 034217 006145 065024 165072 133002
0000400 103715 125242 164653 074715 144536 144526 162207 043514
0000420 155712 103241 136332 003453 163701 177367 032710 172053
0000440 123476 001211 041234 023367 152535 155027 131060 001542
0000460 154654 004641 023171 140003 105740 153243 156333 175570
```

Comment: If these devices were part of an md RAID and haven't been wiped then ```sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sda``` should give some information, so please show us that for both of the devices.

Comment: @grifferz it shows `mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda` for both devices